# Adding pdf icon in AEM rich text editor

Tags: aem, rte

I have a requirement where author can embed/link url/pdf in rte and if pdf is added, a pdf icon should be shown very next to link itself. What i have thought of

1. Customize OOTB RTE
2. Update css/js to add icon if pdf is recognized.

Anything better to suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Use CSS, there is no need to customize RTE if you don't really have to. Take a look at this article: https://askthecssguy.com/articles/showing-hyperlink-cues-with-css/

Comment: Seem fine to me. Thanks for help.